# Change directory and run a command to import using C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do this

> cd C:\SLP\SLP5
> C:\SLP\SLP5>slp importtextfile -u -c -n -fplu C:\SLP\SLP5\Update.csv

using cmd. Basically, change the directory and then run the command: `slp importtextfile -u -c -n -fplu C:\SLP\SLP5\Update`. This works when I run it straight from the cmd.

Now I'm trying to do it using C # but I can't seem to get it right. This is what I have tried

```
using (Process myProcess = new Process())
{
   myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";*
   myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;    
   myProcess .StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   myProcess .StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
   myProcess .StartInfo .CreateNoWindow = true;
   myProcess.Start();
   myProcess .StandardInput.WriteLine(@"cd C:\SLP\SLP5\");
   myProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"slp importtextfile –u –c –n –fplu C:\SLP\SLP5\Update.csv");
   SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
   string s = myProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
   textBox1.Text = s;
   myProcess .WaitForExit();
   var exitCode = myProcess .ExitCode;
   myProcess .Close();
}
```

It cant seem to work, can someone please help

Comment: set property ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory instead of calling 

myProcess .StandardInput.WriteLine(@"cd C:\SLP\SLP5\");

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory?view=net-5.0

Comment: SendKeys cannot work when you don't have a window.  Cmd.exe won't terminate unless you write the EXIT command.  Use ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory to avoid having to write a CD command.  Quite pointless to use cmd.exe at all, it gets in the way, simply start slp.exe directly.